# unwrap Option type got error : cannot move out of `*foo` which is behind a shared reference

Tags: rust

if we have the code below:

```rust
struct Config {
    username: Option<String>,
    password: Option<String>,
}

fn some_fn(config: Config) {
    let foo: &Option<String> = &config.username;
    let bar: Option<&String> = config.username.as_ref();
    let name1 = foo.unwrap(); // error
    let name2 = bar.unwrap(); // no error
}
```

I got error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*foo` which is behind a shared reference
   --> src\main.rs:9:17
    |
9   |     let name1 = foo.unwrap();
    |                 ^^^^--------
    |                 |   |
    |                 |   `*foo` moved due to this method call
    |                 help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
    |                 move occurs because `*foo` has type `Option<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |
note: `Option::<T>::unwrap` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `*foo`
```

and I look into the `unwrap` method, it is something like this:

```
    pub const fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        match self {
            Some(val) => val,
            None => panic("called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value"),
        }
    }
```

Actually I don't know what does "something is behind a shared reference" really means. at first glance I was thinking, `unwrap` takes a `self` param, but the `foo` got a type of `&Option<String>`, it is a reference, so error make sense. but if I change the type of bar to a reference, like this:

```
    let bar: &Option<&String> = &config.username.as_ref();
    let name2 = bar.unwrap(); // I thought this time there should be a error while still no error
```

so get back to the issue, the key difference is between `&Option<String>` and `&Option<&String>`, I just don't know what does the error means,"`*foo` moved due to this method call", why `*foo` can't move into `unwrap`?

what is REALLY cause of this issue?

Comment: In your `foo.unwrap()` example with the error, `foo` probably has type `&Option<String>`. As such, your intuition about `unwrap` taking `self` is correct. The thing that obscures this a little is that `&…` is `Copy`, and thus is `Option<&…>`, so Rust will automatically copy `bar` before `.unwrap()`, avoiding the error in the last example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually I don't know what does "something is behind a shared reference" really means.

That it's inside of / behind an `&` (a shared reference).

> at first glance I was thinking, unwrap takes a self param, but the foo got a type of &Option, it is a reference, so error make sense.

That's exactly the cause of the issue. `unwrap` takes the `Option` by value, you're trying to call it on a reference, so it tries to call the method on `*foo` (in order to get an owned value), which is not valid: a `String` is not `Copy`, so a `Option<String>` is not `Copy` either, therefore `*foo` needs to move the value, and it's not possible to move a value out of a shared reference.

The second case works because `bar` is an `&Option<&T>`, and a reference is always `Copy`, which also makes the option `Copy`, so `*bar` is valid. Hence `unwrap` compiles just fine.

You can see it by just dereferencing, no need to even involve `unwrap`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo: &Option<String> = &None;
    let bar: &Option<&String> = &None;
    
    // *foo;  // cannot move out of `*foo` which is behind a shared reference
    *bar;
}
```

Comment: awesome! but I have two further question: 1> " so it tries to call the method on *foo", in original question there is no `*foo`, you mean `unwrap` takes value so there is some automatic dereference mechanism in rust? 2> "and it's not possible to move a value out of a shared reference.",in your dereferencing example, it's hard to accept that , `foo` and `bar` looks like both are `&None` , but different type definition makes `*foo` got a error while `*bar` not.

Comment: "in original question there is no *foo, you mean unwrap takes value so there is some automatic dereference mechanism in rust?" [yes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#wheres-the---operator): " when you call a method with object.something(), Rust automatically adds in &, &mut, or * so object matches the signature of the method." because `unwrap` takes an `Option`, calling it on a `&Option` implicitly dereferences.

Comment: "foo and bar looks like both are &None , but different type definition makes *foo got a error while *bar not" values are irrelevant, they are different *types*, so their static capabilities differ. `bar` implements [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) which means it can be implicitly duplicated, while `foo` does not, and can't be. This is routine, `1` can be used to initialise a `usize` or a `u8`, yet only the former can be used to index a `Vec`.